# Expand cursor length QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlineedit

I'd like to take a normal `QLineEdit`, and change the shape of the cursor. So with a subclass like so:

```
class myLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:

public:
    explicit myLineEdit(QWidget * parent = 0)
    {

    }

protected:

};
```

And make it so that the cursor is several pixels wide, like that of a Linux terminal. By default, the cursor to indicate text position is very slim.

I assume I need to override something in the `paintevent()`? What exactly in the `paintevent` would be responsible for drawing the single pixel blinking line `QLineEdit()` defaults to? I could not find this information in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Qproxystyle:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class LineEditStyle: public QProxyStyle
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int cursorWidth READ cursorWidth WRITE setCursorWidth)
public:
    using QProxyStyle::QProxyStyle;
    int cursorWidth() const{
        if(m_cursor_width < 0)
            return baseStyle()->pixelMetric(PM_TextCursorWidth);
        return pixelMetric(PM_TextCursorWidth);
    }
    void setCursorWidth(int cursorWidth){
        m_cursor_width = cursorWidth;
    }
    int pixelMetric(QStyle::PixelMetric metric, const QStyleOption *option = nullptr, const QWidget *widget = nullptr) const override
    {
        if(metric == PM_TextCursorWidth)
            if(m_cursor_width > 0)
                return  m_cursor_width;
        return  QProxyStyle::pixelMetric(metric, option, widget);
    }
private:
    int m_cursor_width = -1;
};

class LineEdit: public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LineEdit(QWidget *parent = nullptr):
        QLineEdit(parent)
    {
        LineEditStyle *new_style = new LineEditStyle(style());
        new_style->setCursorWidth(10);
        setStyle(new_style);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    LineEdit w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

[image]

Comment: I had actually tried something similar but it was for Qt4.x and I'm using Qt5 but I'm going to give this a try and report back, thanks.

Comment: @progro QProxyStyle only existed in Qt4 since 4.6 (latest versions), but in Qt4 it is already fully available. Are you using Qt5?

Comment: I'm using Qt5.9 and this doesn't compile - error: undefined reference to `vtable for LineEdit' , any ideas? I tried clean project & run qmake, and also tried to remove the Q_OBJECT macro, none of that worked.ANy ideas?

Comment: @progro If you are using my code only in the main.cpp then you must add main.moc: `"#include "main.moc"` at the end of the file, execute `build -> run qmake` and compile again. and if you are copying it to another file then delete main.moc

Comment: @progro some feedback?

Comment: Yep, that works! Thanks! If you're looking for work I'd like to keep your information on file, please send me your email if available (I couldn't find it on your paypal page).

Comment: @progro see my github: https://github.com/eyllanesc there is my contact information

Comment: Thanks! Just a FYI - I played with the code a bit and since nothing is actually being animated the Q_OBJECT & Q_PROPERTY calls aren't necessary, so if you get rid of the "using QProxyStyle::QProxyStyle;" and replace it with "LineEditStyle(QStyle *style = 0) : QProxyStyle(style)" you can delete the Q_OBJECT, Q_PROPERTY, & "#include "main.moc" which'll shorten and simplify the code.

Comment: @progro No, in Qt the qproperties serve to make explicit that the property exists, besides they are only 2 extra lines

Comment: OK, I'd like to learn more about that - can you show where in the documentation it says Q_PROPERTY must be declared in this case of a non animated subclass? because there is a very similar code here - https://forum.qt.io/topic/1137/change-qlineedit-text-cursor-shape/4 - on the Qt forums and there is no Q_OBJECT, moc, Q_PROPERTY, so I don't believe it necessary. Besides, it works fine without it and makes compilation much easier.

Comment: @progro I had not seen that post, as I say it does not help in anything to the particular solution but in the reading of the code. On the other hand you have had a problem in the compilation because it seems that you are a newbie in the Qt. In conclusion I do not see that these 2 lines cause problem so I will not eliminate it

Comment: Lol... it's not necessary but whatever, good luck with your donations!

Comment: I have found more bugs in your code. This is low quality!

Comment: @progro What bugs? Could you be explicit? Perhaps I can correct them