# How to make cursor of LineEdit thinner in the input mask mode?

Tags: qt, qlineedit

this is the cursor in normal mode of LineEdit

[image]

and this is the cursor when there is input mask

[image]

As you see the cursor with input mask is thicker. How can I modify QLineEdit to get the thin cursor as in normal mode for input mask?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932632/expand-cursor-length-qlineedit

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is anything you can do without re-implementing the `QLineEdit`.

But I do not think you should. The look of the cursor has a meaning:

- A thin cursor, positioned between characters, means that you will insert text, moving the already existing text.
- A fat cursor, highlighting a character, means that you will replace text, overwriting existing text.

Note that this is not a Qt thing, this is universal. For instance if you open a command prompt, pressing the "Insert" key will change the cursor from one mode to another;

When you use an input mask, the `QLineEdit` works in replace mode so it is perfectly fine to have a fat cursor.

Forcing the cursor to display in thin mode would be misleading users and is a really poor UX idea.

#### Edit

Another solution would be to use a `QValidator` like the [`QRegularExpressionValidator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionvalidator.html). It is not exactly the same behaviour as an input mask, but it serves the same purpose and will not force the insert-mode.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I also have same thinking as yours. But I am just a developer, do not have the right to decide :)

Comment: @songvan I have added an alternative to my answer. On another topic, it is not because you are not the decider on a project, that you should not try to explain why their decision is bad (like changing how cursor behaved in the last 40+ years). It is even more necessary when the decider is not the end user, because then you will have complaint from the user and you will have to undo/redo what you have done. Also generally you have the argument of money on your side: doing non-standard "stupid" things takes more development time and cost more money.